# looping through a vector of iterators with an iterator

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, iterator

I get an error in the final for loop:

```
error: conversion from '__normal_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >*,vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >>>' to non-scalar type '__normal_iterator<const int*,vector<int>>' requested

   20 | for(vector<int>::const_iterator t=ind.begin(); t != ind.end(); ++t){

      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~^~
```

I kept looking for solutions to similar problems and I still don't get what I did wrong.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n,m,a;
vector<int>::iterator b;
cin>>n>>m;
vector<int> seq(n);
vector<vector<int>::iterator> ind;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>seq[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    cin>>a;
    b=find(seq.begin(),seq.end(),a);
    if(b!=seq.end()){
        ind.push_back(b);
    }
}
sort(ind.begin(),ind.end());
for(vector<int>::const_iterator t=ind.begin(); t != ind.end(); ++t){
    cout<<*t;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the error message and point to line 20

Comment: _"I get an error on line 20"_. What error and where is line 20? Also maybe you are interested in [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Please indent & space out your code in a way that makes it easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector<int>::const_iterator` is an iterator for a `vector` of `int`. An iterator for a vector of iterators is `vector<vector<int>::iterator>::const_iterator`.

To avoid typing such monster types, use `auto`:

```
for(auto t=ind.begin(); t != ind.end(); ++t){
    cout<<*t;
}
```

or when you iterate from begin till end, a range based loop:

```
for(auto t : ind){
    cout<<t;
}
```

As you didnt include the error (at the time of writing this) I fixed only the obvious error. I suppose you need to dereference the iterator to print the actual element (ie add a `*` in both examples above).

Comment: when I did what you said in the first solution I get these errors:

Comment: 't' does not name a type / expected ';' before 't' / 't' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @YoussefMaghrebi when your question is answered and problem solved you should accept one of the answer.

Comment: i don't know how to do it, could you tell me ?

Answer (score 2):

The vector `ind` is a vector of elements of the type `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

So in the for loop you have to write at least like

```
vector<vector<int>::iterator>::const_iterator t=ind.begin();
```

And it seems within the loop you mean

```
 cout<<**t;
```

instead of

```
cout<<*t;
```

Comment: thank you now it works can you explain further why ** ? is it a pointer on a pointer or something? I'm kinda new to c++

Comment: @YoussefMaghrebi t is an iterator that "points" to iterators. So the first dereferencing gives an iterator that you need to dereference the second time to get the pointed value.